# Radio Buttons on bootstrap table not working with IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I want to put radio button inside a table (rendered with twitter bootstrap).
The problem is the radio button is not working with IE8 (impossible to click).
It works perfectly with FF or Chrome.

The fiddlecode : http://jsfiddle.net/WuBa5/8/ but fiddle seems to not work on IE8.

Here is the code :

```
<table class="table table-striped  table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Choisir</th>
        <th>Version</th>
        <th>Date de Création</th>
        <th>Commentaire</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Versions">
    <tr data-bind="    attr: { 'name': $index }" name="0">
        <td>
            <input type="radio" data-bind="    value: id" name="radiosImport" value="bb1e7d68-fef4-7e4a-bbfe-c39238d2e712"></td>
        <td data-bind="    text: name">1.0</td>
        <td data-bind="    text: commitDate">Version ouverte non archivée</td>
        <td data-bind="    text: description">Initialisation de la base de données 12-08-2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="    attr: { 'name': $index }" name="1">
        <td>
            <input type="radio" data-bind="    value: id" name="radiosImport" value="aa6f304d-696d-ac41-9e7c-d4ef02dc5711"></td>
        <td data-bind="    text: name">1.1</td>
        <td data-bind="    text: commitDate">Version ouverte non archivée</td>
        <td data-bind="    text: description">MAJ DB</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle to demo the issue?

Comment: here you go : http://jsfiddle.net/WuBa5/8
But I cannot open jsfiddle with IE8

Comment: so after further research this small exemple seems to work with IE8 but on my application it doesn't. The table is displayed on modal window maybe it is that.

Comment: I found another exemple which is not working with IE8. http://vandelaydesign.com/demos/bootstrap-modal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the answer. 
The problem is with JQuery not auto-closing the *input* tag.
I changed the JQuery code to generate the input with :

```
tdbodyRadio.append("<input type='radio' data-bind='value: id' name='radiosImport' onchange='EventOnModal.onClickRadio();'/>");
```